# Firefox ReferenceError: browser is not defined, API browser.downloads.download

Tags: javascript, firefox

Can anyone help me understand why it doesn't work in FF and what I need to do to make it work?

**index.html**

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script type="application/javascript"
src="https://unpkg.com/webextension-polyfill@0.2.1/dist/browser-polyfill.min.js">
</script>
<script>
function onStartedDownload(id) {
  console.log(`Started downloading: ${id}`);
}

function onFailed(error) {
  console.log(`Download failed: ${error}`);
}

var downloadUrl = "https://sample-videos.com/img/Sample-jpg-image-50kb.jpg";

var downloading = browser.downloads.download({
  url : downloadUrl,
  filename : 'my-image-again.png',
  conflictAction : 'uniquify',
  saveAs : 'true'
});

downloading.then(onStartedDownload, onFailed);
</script>
```

I use only one file index.html

The download() function of the downloads API downloads a file, given its URL and other optional preferences.

**Code Snippet**

```js
function onStartedDownload(id) {
  console.log(`Started downloading: ${id}`);
}

function onFailed(error) {
  console.log(`Download failed: ${error}`);
}

var downloadUrl = "https://sample-videos.com/img/Sample-jpg-image-50kb.jpg";

var downloading = browser.downloads.download({
  url : downloadUrl,
  filename : 'my-image-again.png',
  conflictAction : 'uniquify',
  saveAs : 'true'
});

downloading.then(onStartedDownload, onFailed);
```

```html
<meta charset="utf-8">
```